# Unique Identifier for each Addon user

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So far I have been just playing around with the Addon SDK and making tools for my own use.

I had in mind the idea to possibly try to do something like one of those extensions that adds a profile theme to your Facebook profile, as well as letting others with the extension see your theme when they visit your Facebook profile.

I'm just kind of thinking out what I may do, and what I was wondering is - I know the addon will have a unique ID, but is there anything inherent I can use to identify each unique Addon user? I.e. to tie them to the stored data with their theme information?

If anyone has experience with this - how did you approach it?

Maybe I could set a cookie as the Addon that lasts a year or something, and then keep resetting it each time the browser is opened, and hope for the best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Add-on SDK you are probably best off by using [simple-storage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/simple-storage.html). You can also use `makeUuid()` function in the `xpcom` package to generate a guaranteed unique identifier. Something like this:

```js
var ss = require("simple-storage");
if (!("UserID" in ss))
{
  // We were just installed, generate user ID
  var xpcom = require("xpcom");
  ss.UserID = xpcom.makeUuid()
}
console.log("User ID: " + ss.UserID);
```

Please make sure that you have a privacy policy where you explain that you generate a user identifier and what you use it for.

Comment: Thanks once again - I think Mozilla should pay you if they don't already! :P

Comment: One follow-up question - So any data stored in simple storage will be persistently available pretty much no matter what? Unless either the Addon or FF are uninstalled I'm assuming?

Comment: @delta9: I guess so. I'm not sure whether the data is removed upon uninstall - try it.

Comment: Am testing it out now - am using your exact code above but console is showing the UserID value = undefined.. :( Any more light you can shed for me? It appears there is absolutely 0 information on the xpcom module available in the Addon SDK docs.. It's not even listed on the hub, though you can find the (mostly blank) page if you search Google...

Comment: nevermind, the xpcom code is working after a bit of tweaking, I think I need to look at the simple-storage part but it's documented so I should be able to figure it out... if not you may see a new question about it in the next day or two!! :P thanks again man, you are without a doubt the resident FF guru and I really appreciate the time you spend here helping us n00bs! :)

Comment: @SuvP: Please don't hijack discussions, these have only a few participants who might not be too interested in your question (in particular, after five years). Just create a question and feel free to reference the discussion here if it adds any context.